# Where to Place Image folder and java script folder in my project

Tags: javascript, image, project

I am developing one project through eclipse. But I don't know where to place image files and JavaScript files in eclipse. Do you have any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: There is Google for that and the documentation of eclipse

Comment: put it under WebContent folder....

Answer (score 0):

put it under WebContent folder....

you can also make folder for javascript and images under WebContent